# How to keep/add single string item to firestore collection using collection add method?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am going to keep the favorite words into firestore collection.

I have created a collection reference using "words-track".
 Then added the word item to collection reference by add() method.

```
fun <T> setItemRx(
        collection: String,
        item: T
    ): Completable {
        var ref = firestore.collection(collection)
        return setItemRx(ref, item)
    }

    fun <T> setItemRx(
        ref: CollectionReference,
        item: T
    ): Completable {
        return Completable.create { emitter ->
            RxCompletableHandler.assignOnTask(emitter, ref.add(item!!))
        }
    }

    public static <T> void assignOnTask(CompletableEmitter emitter, Task<T> task) {
        RxCompletableHandler<T> handler = new RxCompletableHandler<>(emitter);
        task.addOnFailureListener(handler);
        task.addOnSuccessListener(handler);
        try {
            task.addOnCompleteListener(handler);
        } catch (Throwable error) {
            Timber.e(error);
        }
    }
```

The word item need to be added into "words-track" collection.

Comment: Does it not work? Are you having errors?

Comment: I have got error like IllegalArguementException and later it suggested to work with Map<String,Object>. But I want to keep string list to "words-track". Could you please suggest any idea to achieve it?

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace of this error?